# Python: How would I get an average of a set of tuples?

Tags: python

I have a problem I attempting to solve this problem.

I have a function that produces tuples. I attempted to store them in an array in this method

```
while(loops til exhausted)
    count = 0
    set_of_tuples[count] = function(n,n,n)
    count = count + 1
```

apparently python doesn't store variables this way. How can I go about storing a set of tuples in a variable and then averaging them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in a couple ways.  Here is one:

```
set_of_tuples = []
while `<loop-condition>`:
    set_of_tuples.append(function(n, n, n))
```

If you want to average the results element-wise, you can:

```
average = tuple(sum(x[i] for x in set_of_tuples) / len(set_of_tuples)
                for i in range(len(set_of_tuples[0])))
```

If this is numerical data, you probably want to use Numpy instead.  If you were using a Numpy array, you would just:

```
average = numpy.average(arr, axis=0)
```

Comment: Note that a better name for the variable would be `list_of_tuples` ... As that isn't a `set`.

Comment: @mgilson: That's not necessarily true.  It might be a set, even if it's not a `set`.

Comment: Plain ol' `tuples` or maybe `result_tuples` would be the best name, probably, but if each tuple represents something concrete, using that in the name would be even better.

Comment: @kindall: It's obviously just a stand-in for the actual variable name.  No use discussing naming conventions for stand-ins.

Comment: @DietrichEpp  If it was a set you would use `.add()` instead of `.append()`

Comment: @jamylak: You seem to be misunderstanding the difference between a set and a `set`.  One is a mathematical concept, the other is a concrete type.  That's the difference I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, your psuedo-code is not Python at all.  You might want to look at something more like:

```
## count = 0
set_of_tuples = list()
while not exhausted():
    set_of_tuples.append(function(n,n,n))
    ## count += 1
count = len(set_of_tuples)
```

However, here the count is superfluous since we can just *len(set_of_tuples)* after the loop if we want.  Also the name "set_of_tuples" is a pretty poor choice; especially given that it's not a set.